# Extending MAUI iOS API Bindings for iOS 16.1

Tags: c#, ios, swift, maui, maui-ios

I'm looking to access the Extended Dynamic Range APIs introduced in iOS 16 for the Core Animation Metal Layer, specifically the [wantsExtendedDynamicRangeContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer/1478161-wantsextendeddynamicrangecontent/) and [edrMetadata](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer/3182052-edrmetadata) attributes of the CAMetalLayer in .NET MAUI 7. Unfortunately, it appears that these APIs have not been exposed even in MAUI 7 iOS 16.1 Bindings SDK.

The version of maui-ios that is installed and the ios version that that is compatible with is:

| Library | Version | VS Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| maui-ios | 7.0.52/7.0.100 | VS 17.4.33213.308 |
| ios | 16.1.1477/7.0.100 | VS 17.4.33213.308 |

How would I go about implementing a Swift library that sets these attributes of CAMetalLayer?

For further reference, I have also opened an issue on the github for MAUI's iOS bindings: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17340

Comment: Have you tried the preview versions of VS? It sometimes takes some time for the latest API's to be available

Comment: I have, this is the latest version said to be compatible with iOS 16.1 - the bindings have been around since iOS 16.0.